# Where is the missing altar?

Tags: passover, korban, zionism, korban-pesach, temple-service-avoda

Each year a a group of individuals receive news coverage (for example [here](http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/262038)) for attempting to enter the Har Habayit to bring the Pesach Offfering. (They are stopped by the police.) Since the Korban Pesach requires giving blood on the Altar and the Altar is not standing, nor do the intruders seem to carry an altar with them; how can they bring the Korban Pesach? Do they expect the Mizbeach to fall from heaven? Or is it simply a publicity stunt?
 Or is there possibly an halachic opinion that does not require use of the Altar?

Comment: הלכות קרבן פסח - פרק ראשון הלכה ג אֵין שׁוֹחֲטִין אֶת הַפֶּסַח אֶלָּא בַּעֲזָרָה כִּשְׁאָר הַקָּדָשִׁים. אַף בִּשְׁעַת הֶתֵּר הַבָּמוֹת לֹא הָיוּ מַקְרִיבִין אֶת הַפֶּסַח בְּבָמַת יָחִיד וְכָל הַמַּקְרִיב אֶת הַפֶּסַח בְּבָמַת יָחִיד לוֹקֶה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים טז-ה) 'לֹא תוּכַל לִזְבֹּחַ אֶת הַפָּסַח בְּאַחַד שְׁעָרֶיךָ'. מִפִּי הַשְּׁמוּעָה לָמְדוּ שֶׁזּוֹ אַזְהָרָה לַשּׁוֹחֵט בְּבָמַת יָחִיד אֲפִלּוּ בִּשְׁעַת הֶתֵּר הַבָּמוֹת:

Comment: THe way I understand these people, they try to go as far as they could. Kind of נשלמה פרים שפתינו - their purpose is to remember, not to actually fulfill the Mitzvah. Each time they progress further and further, and maybe one day they will build something.

Comment: to clarify I am NOT talking about the "Practice" or "Demonstration" Korbanot, which have been held in recent years OUTSIDE the mikdash.

Comment: @DannySchoemann They certainly would be in the Azara. I don't understand the relevance?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi - just saying - it seems that without an Altar there's nothing to talk about. (Not an answer, that's why it's in a comment.)

Comment: Naftali Tzvi, in many ways it really is just a publicity stunt - they're aware that they - and all Jews - still can't freely do what they wish on Har Habayit - but wish to bring attention to the situation.

Comment: https://www.temple.org.il/single-post/2017/07/04/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%91%D7%97-%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: @Mordechai Do you think they carry a mizbeach?